# SceneKit and Rotation around a point due to user swipe

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am continuing a project from somebody else, in which I am looking at code that I do not really understand. I have not worked with SceneKit before ... so I am trying to learn as much as I can.

We show an object in an SCNView.

- The user can swipe with one finger, to rotate the object up, down, left or right. So, rotate around an axis perpendicular to the axis of the camera.
- The user can rotate with 2 fingers to rotate the object around 'the axis of the camera'.
- The user can zoom by pinching with 2 fingers.
- The user can swipe with 2 fingers to slide the object.

I know ... when I say the object moves or rotates, that might actually mean that the object is stationary, but the camera is moving or rotating in the opposite direction.

1. I do not see any GestureRecognisers on the SCNView ... does that mean that there are built in GestureRecognisers (for instance in the SCNView::defaultCameraController)? If so, how can they be slightly altered (in stead of having to completely rebuild this behaviour)?
2. How do I know that the user is doing something (like one or 2 finger drag, or 2 finger rotate)? Like, can I implement a Delegate function or set a closure or Notification or GestureRecogniser handler to see what is happening? I think that if the user is moving the object (two-finger drag) I must change the target of the camera, so that when the user 'single-finger-drags' later on, the object seems to rotate around a different center? The SCNSceneRendererDelegate::renderer,updateAtTime has been implemented, but I fear that gets called with each frame, if the user is doing something or not: Way too often, I think.
3. How can I 'ignore' the two-finger rotate gesture, without loosing the two-finger drag functionality?

Thanks for any assistance!
Wouter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Wouter: What you describe sounds like the default built-in functinality from SceneKit that you can switch on or off on the Scene-View definition itself.

```
sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true/false
```

It allows not much customization (you can actually define a rotation behaviour named turntable, and some others). Keep in mind: as soon as you move the object, resp. the camera, in internal camera-object is produced and the pointOfView switches to that *"invisible"* camera. (a double tap will return to the initial camera and its position)

If you want to implement your own mechanism, you will have to work with Pan-Gestures. Here is a good demonstration project, that shows you some alernatives when it comes to object rotation. Consider you to have a look at it:

https://github.com/gadsden/SceneKit-Quaternion-Rotations